# Salesforce Validations

Tags: validation

I have a requirement like the user can edit any closed opportunity only once after the opportunity is closed . When the user try to edit the opportunity second time after the opportunity is closed it should not allow user to do so.
Please let me know how to achieve it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a trigger that checks whether the Trigger.old Opportunity Status is "Closed Won" or "Closed Lost". If so, it sets a new Checkbox-field to true. Then, you can add a validation rule that checks whether the Checkbox-field is true. This would block users from editing a closed opportunity twice.